# Javascript - Hide / Show element if array is empty

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I want to show/hide `.file__upload` if the number of files in the `fileList` equals the maximum number of allowable files.

Currently when the maximum is met, the element hides successfully, however when I delete an item the element doesn't show again. I think the issue is in the `function delItem(el) {}` not recognizing the number of `files` in the `fileList` and when an item is deleted, it doesn't update the `maxFileNum`.

How do I have the `.file__upload` to show when `fileList.files.length !== maxFileNum`?

```
  var x = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".file__upload");
  let maxFileNum = e.target.getAttribute("data-max"); //Maximum number of files
  if (fileList.files.length > maxFileNum) {
    let tmpf = [];
    err.push(`Limit of ${maxFileNum} allowed`);
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }
  if (fileList.files.length == maxFileNum) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (fileList.files.length < maxFileNum) {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  }
```

```js
const fInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".file>div>input");

function getFileSize(size) {
  let _size = size;
  let unt = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB"],
    i = 0;
  while (_size > 900) {
    _size /= 1024;
    i++;
  }
  return Math.round(_size * 100) / 100 + " " + unt[i];
}

function delItem(el) {
  fileList = {
    files: []
  };
  let fInp = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < fInp.files.length; i++) {
    fileList.files.push(fInp.files[i]);
  }
  fileList.files.splice(el.getAttribute("data-index"), 1);
  fInp.files = createFileList(...fileList.files);
  if (fInp.files.length > 0) {
    el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
      ".file__title"
    ).innerHTML = `${fInp.files.length} File Selected`;
  } else {
    el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
      ".file__title"
    ).innerHTML = "No File Chosen";
  }
  el.parentNode.remove();
}

function fade(element) {
  let op = 1; // initial opacity
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.style.display = "none";
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
  let op = 0.01; // initial opacity
  element.style.opacity = op;
  element.style.display = "flex";
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 13);
}

function get_browser() {
  let ua = navigator.userAgent,
    tem,
    M =
    ua.match(
      /(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i
    ) || [];
  if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
    tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return {
      name: "IE",
      version: tem[1] || ""
    };
  }
  if (M[1] === "Chrome") {
    tem = ua.match(/\bOPR|Edge\/(\d+)/);
    if (tem != null) {
      return {
        name: "Opera",
        version: tem[1]
      };
    }
  }
  M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, "-?"];
  if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) {
    M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
  }
  return {
    name: M[0],
    version: M[1]
  };
}

for (let inp of fInputs) {
  inp.parentNode.querySelector(".file__btn>img").src =
    "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
  inp.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    setPrevData(e);
  });
  inp.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    handleFile(e);
  });
}

let fileList = {
  files: []
};
let fName = null;
let mxSiz = null;

function setPrevData(e) {
  if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple") && fName !== e.target.name) {
    console.log("multiple");
    fName = e.target.name;
    fileList = fileList = {
      files: []
    };
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(e.target.files[i]);
        fileList.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function handleFile(e) {
  let err = [];
  const fLen = e.target.files.length;
  mxSiz = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".file__max");
  mxSiz =
    mxSiz != null &&
    Number(mxSiz.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, "")) * Math.pow(1024, 2);

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple")) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fLen; i += 1) {
      fileList.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
    }
  } else {
    fileList.files.push(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  //type validate
  if (e.target.hasAttribute("accept")) {
    let tmpf = [];
    let type = new RegExp(
      e.target.getAttribute("accept").split(",").join("$|") + "$",
      "gi"
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.files.length; i += 1) {
      if (fileList.files[i].name.match(type)) {
        tmpf.push(fileList.files[i]);
      } else {
        err.push("Wrong File Type Selected");
      }
    }
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }

  //limit validate
  var x = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".file__upload");
  let maxFileNum = e.target.getAttribute("data-max"); //Maximum number of files
  if (fileList.files.length > maxFileNum) {
    let tmpf = [];
    err.push(`Limit of ${maxFileNum} allowed`);
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }
  if (fileList.files.length == maxFileNum) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (fileList.files.length < maxFileNum) {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  }

  // size validate
  if (mxSiz > 0) {
    let tmpf = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.files.length; i += 1) {
      if (fileList.files[i].size < mxSiz) {
        tmpf.push(fileList.files[i]);
        mxSiz -= fileList.files[i].size;
      } else {
        console.log("rejected", i, fileList.files[i].size);
        err.push("Max Upload Size Exceeded");
      }
    }
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple")) {
    e.target.files = createFileList(...fileList.files);
  } else {
    e.target.files = createFileList(fileList.files[fileList.files.length - 1]);
    fileList = {
      files: []
    };
  }

  // set File list view
  if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".file__title").innerHTML =
      e.target.files.length + " File Selected";
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".file__list").innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i += 1) {
      let img = null;
      if (e.target.files[i].type.match(/image-*/)) {
        img = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]);
      } else {
        img =
          "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
      }
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        .querySelector(".file__list")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          `<div>
                    <img src="${img}" alt="img"  title="${
            e.target.files[i].name
          }">
                    <div>
                        <span title="${e.target.files[i].name}">${
            e.target.files[i].name
          }</span>
                        <br/>
                        <small>${getFileSize(e.target.files[i].size)}</small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="delItem(this)" data-index="${i}" title="Remove This File"><span>&times;</span></button>
                </div>`
        );
    }
  }

  // set eror
  if (err.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < err.length; i += 1) {
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        .querySelector(".file__elements")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "afterbegin",
          `
            <div style="background: #fff2f2;color: darkred;display:none" class="file__error">
                <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="img">
                <span>${err[i]}</span>
            </div>`
        );
    }
    const errNods = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(
      ".file__elements>.file__error"
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < errNods.length; i += 1) {
      unfade(errNods[i]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        fade(errNods[i]);
      }, 3000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        errNods[i].remove();
      }, 4000);
    }
    err = [];
  }
}
```

```css
.file__upload {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file__upload>small {
  color: gray;
}

.file__upload>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 35px;
}

.file__upload>button>img {
  width: 24px;
}

.file__upload>button>span,
.file__upload>span,
.file__upload>small {
  vertical-align: super;
}

.file__upload>input {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 37px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file__upload:hover {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.file__list>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}

.file__list>div>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 73%;
}

.file__list>div>div>small {
  color: gray;
}

.file__list>div>img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.file__list>div>div>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.file__list>div>button {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  padding: 0;
}

.file__list>div>button:hover {
  background: #bbbbbb;
}

.file__error {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 46px;
}

.file__error img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="file">
  <div class="file__upload">
    <button class="file__btn" type="button"> <img src="" alt=""> <span> Attach File</span></button>
    <span class="file__title">No File Chosen</span>
    <small class="file__max">(Max 1)</small>
    <input multiple type="file" name="1" data-max="1">
  </div>
  <div class="file__elements">
    <div class="file__list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="file">
  <div class="file__upload">
    <button class="file__btn" type="button"> <img src="" alt=""> <span> Attach File</span></button>
    <span class="file__title">No File Chosen</span>
    <small class="file__max">(Max 3)</small>
    <input multiple type="file" name="1" data-max="3">
  </div>
  <div class="file__elements">
    <div class="file__list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/create-file-list@1.0.1/dist/create-file-list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, just to demonstrate a show/hide issue...

Comment: `let maxFileNum = e.target.getAttribute("data-max");`  <= first thing I would say to try is to convert your value to a number.  Attribute values are all strings.  So if you are going to be performing math or comparisons, you need to convert it first for safety.

Comment: You only call the first bit of code shown in `handleFile`, but you also need to call it in `delItem`. Split the code out into its own function and call it in both places.

Comment: Where is the first code executed, on the onclick event for the button? How are you "deleting" the files? Through changing then in the input?

Comment: @bluejayke When the list item is appended it received the delete button with `onclick="delItem(this)"` which runs the delete function when clicked.

Comment: @kyle first off this part `fileList.files.splice(el.getAttribute("data-index")` may not work because getAttribute returns a string so maybe try parsing it

Comment: Also I don't think you can change the files property of an input, you can just copy it over into a new array and change/use that new array for reference instead

Comment: @HereticMonkey This solution would work best but I am having trouble breaking it out. Would you be able to provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just write the basic idea. that how you can manage your `file uploader` you can use my strategy to implement your solution.

Basically, I am using Map of Map

```
Map <FileUploader1, Map <RandomNumber, File Object>>
Map <FileUploader2, Map <RandomNumber, File Object>>
```

Every time I Add a file I check the size of submap of the file uploader

like `Map.get(FileUploader1).size`

And one more thing you can file uploaders as many as you want, but you just have to use following dom structure!

```
 <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse  <input type="file" id="myFile2" multiple size="2" data-max="2" onchange="addFile(this)" />
    </div>
```

`id="myFile2"` Id should be unique for every file uploader.

Have a look at the code snippet. you will understand! I tried to write a simple and pure javascript code.

```js
 var imageSrc = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
    let fileCollection = new Map();


    function getFileSize(size) {
        let _size = size;
        let unt = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB"],
            i = 0;
        while (_size > 900) {
            _size /= 1024;
            i++;
        }
        return Math.round(_size * 100) / 100 + " " + unt[i];
    }

    function addFile(element) {
        var txt = "";
        var innerHTML = "";

        var elementId = element.id;
        var files = element.files;
        var maxNumberOfFile = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-max"), 10); 
        var mxSiz = element.parentNode.querySelector('.file__max');
        mxSiz = mxSiz != null && Number(mxSiz.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, "")) * Math.pow(1024, 2);

        /* 
        if fileCollection.get(elementId) === undefined it means fileCollection Map don't have any entry to this 
        specific File Uploader so add this File uploader in our fileCollection Map
        */
        if (fileCollection.get(elementId) === undefined)
            fileCollection.set(elementId, new Map());

        if ('files' in element) {
            if (files.length == 0)
                txt = "Select one or more files.";
            else if (files.length > maxNumberOfFile)
                txt = `No more than ${maxNumberOfFile} files`;
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                    if (fileCollection.get(elementId).size < maxNumberOfFile) {

                        var file = files[i];
                        if(mxSiz < file.size)
                        {
                            txt += `File : ${file.name} size is more than mentioned size: ${getFileSize(file.size)} . Max size is: ${getFileSize(mxSiz)} <br/>`;
                            continue;
                        }

                        var randomFileId = randomNumber(1, 9999);
                        fileCollection.get(elementId).set(randomFileId, file);

                        innerHTML += `<div class="file-container">
                        <span>
                        <img src="${imageSrc}" alt="img" class="file-icon">
                        </span>
                        <div style="display: inline-grid;">
                            <span class="align-self-top">${file.name}</span>
                            <span class="align-self-base">${getFileSize(file.size)}</span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="align-self-center close-button"><button type="button" onclick="removeFile(this, ${randomFileId}, ${elementId})" title="Remove This File" ><span>&times;</span></button></span>
                        </div>`;
                    }
                    else {
                        txt = `No more than ${maxNumberOfFile} files`;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (element.value == "") {
                txt += "Select one or more files.";
            }
            else {
                txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
                txt += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + element.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
            }
        }

        // create a files container for specific file uploader.
        var fileListContainerId = "file-list-container-" + elementId;
        var fileListContainer = document.getElementById(fileListContainerId);
        if (fileListContainer === null) {
            fileListContainer = document.createElement('div');
            fileListContainer.className = "file-list-container";
            fileListContainer.id = fileListContainerId;

            // Adding container under File upload
            insertAfter(fileListContainer, document.querySelector("#" + elementId).parentNode);
            // Append HTML dom under File Upload
            document.getElementById(fileListContainer.id).innerHTML += innerHTML;
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(fileListContainerId).innerHTML += innerHTML; // Files container already present in dom just add file in container.

            if(txt !== "")
                document.getElementById(fileListContainerId).innerHTML = txt;


        showHideuploader(element);

    }

    function showHideuploader(element) {
        if (fileCollection.get(element.id).size >= element.getAttribute("data-max"))
            element.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        else
            element.parentNode.style.display = "block";
    }


    // just to create randomNumber for file object
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    function removeFile(button, fileId, uploader) {
        button.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        fileCollection.get(uploader.id).delete(fileId);

        showHideuploader(uploader);
    }

    function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }
```

```css
    .gap {

        height: 200px;
    }

    .file-container {
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid #eeeded;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: #eeeded;

    }

    .file-icon {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .align-self-center {
        align-self: center;
    }


    .align-self-top {
        align-self: flex-start;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }

    .align-self-base {
        align-self: flex-end;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .close-button {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .btn-file {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .btn-default {
        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #ccc;
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .btn-file input[type=file] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: right;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
        outline: none;
        background: white;
        cursor: inherit;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" data-max="3" onchange="addFile(this)" />
        <small class="file__max">(Max 1 MB)</small>
    </div>

    <div class="gap"> </div>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse <input type="file" id="myFile2" multiple size="50" data-max="3" onchange="addFile(this)" />
        <small class="file__max">(Max 1 MB)</small>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>


</html>
```

Rest of the condition you have to write! I just helped you in solving the hide show issue with multiple uploaders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dupinder. I do however need the other functionality to work like it did in the question and am having trouble re-introducing these features into your solution

Comment: Could you please tell me what else is missing in this solution!

Comment: The most important components of the question code were the thumbnail images on the upload list items and the file size limit. Adding these to your code would be good for a solution

Comment: `file max size` limit is added and the `max number` of file feature added and `hide show browser button` is working file.  the `thumbnail` is also attached! working fine from my side.


BTW use my solution's basic idea as I mentioned that I am using Map, and you can build whatever you want to build

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is only showing the file image as the thumbnail preview and not the uploaded image for each item.

Comment: I didn't get it!  It's actually very hard to understand!... What do you mean by uploaded each file 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220560/discussion-between-kyle-underhill-and-dupinder-singh).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your code is just following code in `delItem` function

```
      el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.style.display = "flex";
```

This will detect that the inside `file__list` the elements are deleted so now have to rest state of visibility for `upload div`

```js
    const fInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".file>div>input");

    function getFileSize(size) {
      let _size = size;
      let unt = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB"],
        i = 0;
      while (_size > 900) {
        _size /= 1024;
        i++;
      }
      return Math.round(_size * 100) / 100 + " " + unt[i];
    }

    function delItem(el) { debugger;
      fileList = {
        files: []
      };
      let fInp = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
      for (let i = 0; i < fInp.files.length; i++) {
        fileList.files.push(fInp.files[i]);
      }
      fileList.files.splice(el.getAttribute("data-index"), 1);
      fInp.files = createFileList(...fileList.files);
      if (fInp.files.length > 0) {
        el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
          ".file__title"
        ).innerHTML = `${fInp.files.length} File Selected`;
      } else {
        el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
          ".file__title"
        ).innerHTML = "No File Chosen";
      }

     el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.style.display = "flex";


      el.parentNode.remove();
      

        
      
    }

    function fade(element) {
      let op = 1; // initial opacity
      let timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (op <= 0.1) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          element.style.display = "none";
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
      }, 50);
    }

    function unfade(element) {
      let op = 0.01; // initial opacity
      element.style.opacity = op;
      element.style.display = "flex";
      let timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (op >= 1) {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
      }, 13);
    }

    function get_browser() {
      let ua = navigator.userAgent,
        tem,
        M =
        ua.match(
          /(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i
        ) || [];
      if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
        tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return {
          name: "IE",
          version: tem[1] || ""
        };
      }
      if (M[1] === "Chrome") {
        tem = ua.match(/\bOPR|Edge\/(\d+)/);
        if (tem != null) {
          return {
            name: "Opera",
            version: tem[1]
          };
        }
      }
      M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, "-?"];
      if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) {
        M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
      }
      return {
        name: M[0],
        version: M[1]
      };
    }

    for (let inp of fInputs) {
      inp.parentNode.querySelector(".file__btn>img").src =
        "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
      inp.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        setPrevData(e);
      });
      inp.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        handleFile(e);
      });
    }

    let fileList = {
      files: []
    };
    let fName = null;
    let mxSiz = null;

    function setPrevData(e) {
      if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple") && fName !== e.target.name) {
        console.log("multiple");
        fName = e.target.name;
        fileList = fileList = {
          files: []
        };
        if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i += 1) {
            console.log(e.target.files[i]);
            fileList.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function handleFile(e) {
      let err = [];
      const fLen = e.target.files.length;
      mxSiz = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".file__max");
      mxSiz =
        mxSiz != null &&
        Number(mxSiz.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, "")) * Math.pow(1024, 2);

      if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple")) {
        for (let i = 0; i < fLen; i += 1) {
          fileList.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
        }
      } else {
        fileList.files.push(e.target.files[0]);
      }

      //type validate
      if (e.target.hasAttribute("accept")) {
        let tmpf = [];
        let type = new RegExp(
          e.target.getAttribute("accept").split(",").join("$|") + "$",
          "gi"
        );
        for (let i = 0; i < fileList.files.length; i += 1) {
          if (fileList.files[i].name.match(type)) {
            tmpf.push(fileList.files[i]);
          } else {
            err.push("Wrong File Type Selected");
          }
        }
        fileList.files = tmpf;
      }

      //limit validate
      var x = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".file__upload");
      let maxFileNum = e.target.getAttribute("data-max"); //Maximum number of files
      if (fileList.files.length > maxFileNum) {
        let tmpf = [];
        err.push(`Limit of ${maxFileNum} allowed`);
        fileList.files = tmpf;
      }
      if (fileList.files.length == maxFileNum) {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (fileList.files.length < maxFileNum) {
        x.style.display = "flex";
      }

      // size validate
      if (mxSiz > 0) {
        let tmpf = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < fileList.files.length; i += 1) {
          if (fileList.files[i].size < mxSiz) {
            tmpf.push(fileList.files[i]);
            mxSiz -= fileList.files[i].size;
          } else {
            console.log("rejected", i, fileList.files[i].size);
            err.push("Max Upload Size Exceeded");
          }
        }
        fileList.files = tmpf;
      }

      if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple")) {
        e.target.files = createFileList(...fileList.files);
      } else {
        e.target.files = createFileList(fileList.files[fileList.files.length - 1]);
        fileList = {
          files: []
        };
      }

      // set File list view
      if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
        e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".file__title").innerHTML =
          e.target.files.length + " File Selected";
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".file__list").innerHTML = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i += 1) {
          let img = null;
          if (e.target.files[i].type.match(/image-*/)) {
            img = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]);
          } else {
            img =
              "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
          }
          e.target.parentNode.parentNode
            .querySelector(".file__list")
            .insertAdjacentHTML(
              "beforeend",
              `<div>
                        <img src="${img}" alt="img"  title="${
                e.target.files[i].name
              }">
                        <div>
                            <span title="${e.target.files[i].name}">${
                e.target.files[i].name
              }</span>
                            <br/>
                            <small>${getFileSize(e.target.files[i].size)}</small>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" onclick="delItem(this)" data-index="${i}" title="Remove This File"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    </div>`
            );
        }
      }

      // set eror
      if (err.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < err.length; i += 1) {
          e.target.parentNode.parentNode
            .querySelector(".file__elements")
            .insertAdjacentHTML(
              "afterbegin",
              `
                <div style="background: #fff2f2;color: darkred;display:none" class="file__error">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjg2LjA1NCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyODYuMDU0IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgoKIDxnPgogIDx0aXRsZT5iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPC90aXRsZT4KICA8cmVjdCBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBpZD0iY2FudmFzX2JhY2tncm91bmQiIGhlaWdodD0iNDAyIiB3aWR0aD0iNTgyIiB5PSItMSIgeD0iLTEiLz4KIDwvZz4KIDxnPgogIDx0aXRsZT5MYXllciAxPC90aXRsZT4KICA8ZyBzdHJva2U9Im51bGwiIGlkPSJzdmdfMSI+CiAgIDxwYXRoIHN0cm9rZT0ibnVsbCIgaWQ9InN2Z18yIiBmaWxsPSIjOTEwNjAxIiBkPSJtMTQzLjAyNjk5Nyw1Ni4wMDAwMDVjLTQ4LjA2MDg2NSwwIC04Ny4wMjY5OTcsMzguOTY2MTMxIC04Ny4wMjY5OTcsODcuMDI2OTk3YzAsNDguMDY2MzQyIDM4Ljk2NjEzMSw4Ny4wMjY5OTcgODcuMDI2OTk3LDg3LjAyNjk5N2M0OC4wNjYzNDIsMCA4Ny4wMjY5OTcsLTM4Ljk1NTE3OSA4Ny4wMjY5OTcsLTg3LjAyNjk5N2MwLC00OC4wNjA4NjUgLTM4Ljk2MTI2NCwtODcuMDI2OTk3IC04Ny4wMjY5OTcsLTg3LjAyNjk5N3ptMCwxNTcuNzM2MTY2Yy0zOS4wNTMxNDIsMCAtNzAuNzA5MTY5LC0zMS42NTYwMjcgLTcwLjcwOTE2OSwtNzAuNzA5MTY5czMxLjY1NjAyNywtNzAuNzA5MTY5IDcwLjcwOTE2OSwtNzAuNzA5MTY5czcwLjcwOTE2OSwzMS42NTYwMjcgNzAuNzA5MTY5LDcwLjcwOTE2OXMtMzEuNjU2MDI3LDcwLjcwOTE2OSAtNzAuNzA5MTY5LDcwLjcwOTE2OXptMC4wMDU0NzYsLTExOS41Njk1NThjLTYuMjMzMTIxLDAgLTEwLjk0OTMzNywzLjI1Mjg1NyAtMTAuOTQ5MzM3LDguNTA2OTU2bDAsNDguMTkxMDc3YzAsNS4yNTk1NzYgNC43MTU2MDgsOC41MDE0OCAxMC45NDkzMzcsOC41MDE0OGM2LjA4MTAwNCwwIDEwLjk0OTMzNywtMy4zNzc1OTIgMTAuOTQ5MzM3LC04LjUwMTQ4bDAsLTQ4LjE5MTA3N2MtMC4wMDA2MDgsLTUuMTI5MzY0IC00Ljg2ODMzMywtOC41MDY5NTYgLTEwLjk0OTMzNywtOC41MDY5NTZ6bTAsNzYuMDU2MzY0Yy01Ljk4ODUxOCwwIC0xMC44NjIzMjYsNC44NzM4MDkgLTEwLjg2MjMyNiwxMC44NjcxOTRjMCw1Ljk4MzA0MSA0Ljg3MzgwOSwxMC44NTY4NSAxMC44NjIzMjYsMTAuODU2ODVzMTAuODU2ODUsLTQuODczODA5IDEwLjg1Njg1LC0xMC44NTY4NWMtMC4wMDA2MDgsLTUuOTkzOTk0IC00Ljg2ODMzMywtMTAuODY3MTk0IC0xMC44NTY4NSwtMTAuODY3MTk0eiIvPgogIDwvZz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzMiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzQiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzUiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzYiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzciLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzgiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzkiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzEwIi8+CiAgPGcgaWQ9InN2Z18xMSIvPgogIDxnIGlkPSJzdmdfMTIiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzEzIi8+CiAgPGcgaWQ9InN2Z18xNCIvPgogIDxnIGlkPSJzdmdfMTUiLz4KICA8ZyBpZD0ic3ZnXzE2Ii8+CiAgPGcgaWQ9InN2Z18xNyIvPgogPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4=" alt="img">
                    <span>${err[i]}</span>
                </div>`
            );
        }
        const errNods = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(
          ".file__elements>.file__error"
        );
        for (let i = 0; i < errNods.length; i += 1) {
          unfade(errNods[i]);
          setTimeout(() => {
            fade(errNods[i]);
          }, 3000);
          setTimeout(() => {
            errNods[i].remove();
          }, 4000);
        }
        err = [];
      }
    }
```

```css
    .file__upload>button>img {
      width: 24px;
    }

    .file__upload>button>span,
    .file__upload>span,
    .file__upload>small {
      vertical-align: super;
    }

    .file__upload>input {
      z-index: 100;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 37px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .file__upload:hover {
      background: #fafafa;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .file__list>div {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background: #f8f8f8;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      height: 40px;
    }

    .file__list>div>div {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 73%;
    }

    .file__list>div>div>small {
      color: gray;
    }

    .file__list>div>img {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .file__list>div>div>span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .file__list>div>button {
      background: #e8e8e8;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .file__list>div>button:hover {
      background: #bbbbbb;
    }

    .file__error {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 46px;
    }

    .file__error img {
      width: 46px;
      height: 46px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="file">
      <div class="file__upload">
        <button class="file__btn" type="button"> <img src="" alt=""> <span> Attach File</span></button>
        <span class="file__title">No File Chosen</span>
        <small class="file__max">(Max 1 MB)</small>
        <input multiple type="file" name="1" data-max="3">
      </div>
      <div class="file__elements">
        <div class="file__list">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/create-file-list@1.0.1/dist/create-file-list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added a second instance with a different `data-max` to show that the solution seems to break down for the second instance when `data-max` is greater than 1

Comment: I just tested the solution with `data-max` > 1 and its working fine. please give a try

Comment: If `data-max` is 3 for example, and you add three files, the `.file__upload` is hidden, however if you delete one, the `.file__upload` does not show again. https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/JjXRZje

Comment: Please check now

Comment: I think the solution needs to take into account the `maxFileNum` variable so that the `.file__upload` is hidden only when the maximum number of files is uploaded. If a file is removed after reaching the data-max, then show the `.file__upload` because the fileList doesn't have the max allowed anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220323/discussion-between-dupinder-singh-and-kyle-underhill).

Answer (score 0):

Logic changing display of `.file__upload` was never run after deleteing one of files,
as it was part of `HandleFile()` function, which wasn't invoked there.

I've packed that logic into `toggleElementDisplay()`. I invoke it at `delItem()` and `handleFile()`,
passing ''element'' which display should be changed.

```js
const fInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".file>div>input");

function getFileSize(size) {
  let _size = size;
  let unt = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB"],
    i = 0;
  while (_size > 900) {
    _size /= 1024;
    i++;
  }
  return Math.round(_size * 100) / 100 + " " + unt[i];
}

function toggleDisplay(element) {
  //limit validate
  let maxFileNum = document.querySelector(".file>div>input").getAttribute("data-max"); //Maximum number of files
  if (fileList.files.length == maxFileNum) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (fileList.files.length < maxFileNum) {
    element.style.display = "";
  }
}

function delItem(el) {
  fileList = {
    files: []
  };
  let fInp = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < fInp.files.length; i++) {
    fileList.files.push(fInp.files[i]);
  }
  fileList.files.splice(el.getAttribute("data-index"), 1);
  fInp.files = createFileList(...fileList.files);
  if (fInp.files.length > 0) {
    el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
      ".file__title"
    ).innerHTML = `${fInp.files.length} File Selected`;
  } else {
    el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
      ".file__title"
    ).innerHTML = "No File Chosen";
  }

  
  toggleDisplay(el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling)

  el.parentNode.remove(el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
}

function fade(element) {
  let op = 1; // initial opacity
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.style.display = "none";
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
  let op = 0.01; // initial opacity
  element.style.opacity = op;
  element.style.display = "flex";
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 13);
}

function get_browser() {
  let ua = navigator.userAgent,
    tem,
    M =
    ua.match(
      /(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i
    ) || [];
  if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
    tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return {
      name: "IE",
      version: tem[1] || ""
    };
  }
  if (M[1] === "Chrome") {
    tem = ua.match(/\bOPR|Edge\/(\d+)/);
    if (tem != null) {
      return {
        name: "Opera",
        version: tem[1]
      };
    }
  }
  M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, "-?"];
  if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) {
    M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
  }
  return {
    name: M[0],
    version: M[1]
  };
}

for (let inp of fInputs) {
  inp.parentNode.querySelector(".file__btn>img").src =
    "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
  inp.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    setPrevData(e);
  });
  inp.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    handleFile(e);
  });
}

let fileList = {
  files: []
};
let fName = null;
let mxSiz = null;

function setPrevData(e) {
  if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple") && fName !== e.target.name) {
    console.log("multiple");
    fName = e.target.name;
    fileList = fileList = {
      files: []
    };
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(e.target.files[i]);
        fileList.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function handleFile(e) {
  let err = [];
  const fLen = e.target.files.length;
  mxSiz = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".file__max");
  mxSiz =
    mxSiz != null &&
    Number(mxSiz.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, "")) * Math.pow(1024, 2);

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple")) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fLen; i += 1) {
      fileList.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
    }
  } else {
    fileList.files.push(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  //type validate
  if (e.target.hasAttribute("accept")) {
    let tmpf = [];
    let type = new RegExp(
      e.target.getAttribute("accept").split(",").join("$|") + "$",
      "gi"
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.files.length; i += 1) {
      if (fileList.files[i].name.match(type)) {
        tmpf.push(fileList.files[i]);
      } else {
        err.push("Wrong File Type Selected");
      }
    }
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }
  
  let maxFileNum = document.querySelector(".file>div>input").getAttribute("data-max");
  if (fileList.files.length > maxFileNum) {
    let tmpf = [];
    err.push(`Limit of ${maxFileNum} allowed`);
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }

  //
  toggleDisplay(e.target.parentElement)

  // size validate
  if (mxSiz > 0) {
    let tmpf = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.files.length; i += 1) {
      if (fileList.files[i].size < mxSiz) {
        tmpf.push(fileList.files[i]);
        mxSiz -= fileList.files[i].size;
      } else {
        console.log("rejected", i, fileList.files[i].size);
        err.push("Max Upload Size Exceeded");
      }
    }
    fileList.files = tmpf;
  }

  if (e.target.hasAttribute("multiple")) {
    e.target.files = createFileList(...fileList.files);
  } else {
    e.target.files = createFileList(fileList.files[fileList.files.length - 1]);
    fileList = {
      files: []
    };
  }

  // set File list view
  if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".file__title").innerHTML =
      e.target.files.length + " File Selected";
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".file__list").innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i += 1) {
      let img = null;
      if (e.target.files[i].type.match(/image-*/)) {
        img = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]);
      } else {
        img =
          "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjwhLS0gR2VuZXJhdG9yOiBBZG9iZSBJbGx1c3RyYXRvciAyMi4wLjEsIFNWRyBFeHBvcnQgUGx1Zy1JbiAuIFNWRyBWZXJzaW9uOiA2LjAwIEJ1aWxkIDApICAtLT4NCjxzdmcgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiDQoJIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzNTIgNDI5LjEiIHN0eWxlPSJlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZDpuZXcgMCAwIDM1MiA0MjkuMTsiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPg0KPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4NCgkuc3Qwe2ZpbGw6IzAwNEJCNzt9DQo8L3N0eWxlPg0KPHBhdGggZD0iTTQwOC44LDY2Ljh2MzI3LjRjMCwyNy40LDIyLjgsNDkuOCw1MC4zLDQ5LjhoMjM5LjNjMjcuNSwwLDQ5LjgtMjIuMyw0OS44LTQ5LjhWMTE2Yy0wLjEtMi42LTEuMi01LjItMy4xLTdsLTg4LjktODkuMQ0KCWMtMS45LTEuOS00LjQtMi45LTcuMS0yLjloLTE5MEM0MzEuNiwxNyw0MDguOCwzOS40LDQwOC44LDY2Ljh6IE03MTMuOCwxMDUuOUg2ODNjLTYuMywwLTEyLjQtMi41LTE2LjgtNi45DQoJYy00LjUtNC41LTctMTAuNS02LjktMTYuOHYtMzFMNzEzLjgsMTA1Ljl6IE00MjguOCw2Ni44YzAtMTYuNSwxMy45LTI5LjgsMzAuMy0yOS44aDE4MC4ydjQ1LjFjMCwxMS42LDQuNiwyMi43LDEyLjgsMzENCgljOC4yLDguMiwxOS4zLDEyLjgsMzAuOSwxMi44aDQ1LjF2MjY4LjVjMCwxNi41LTEzLjksMjkuOC0zMC4zLDI5LjhINDU5LjFjLTE2LjYsMC0zMC4zLTEzLjQtMzAuMy0yOS44VjY2Ljh6Ii8+DQo8cGF0aCBjbGFzcz0ic3QwIiBkPSJNMjc3LjIsMTY2LjlIMTMwLjZjLTUuMSwwLTkuMiw0LjEtOS4yLDkuMnM0LjEsOS4yLDkuMiw5LjJoMTQ2LjVjNS4xLDAsOS4yLTQuMSw5LjItOS4xDQoJQzI4Ni40LDE3MSwyODIuMywxNjYuOSwyNzcuMiwxNjYuOXoiLz4NCjxwYXRoIGNsYXNzPSJzdDAiIGQ9Ik05My41LDE2Ni45SDY2LjRjLTUuMSwwLTkuMiw0LjEtOS4yLDkuMnM0LjEsOS4yLDkuMiw5LjJoMjcuMWM1LjEsMCw5LjItNC4xLDkuMi05LjJTOTguNiwxNjYuOSw5My41LDE2Ni45eiINCgkvPg0KPHBhdGggY2xhc3M9InN0MCIgZD0iTTI3Ny4yLDI0MC4zSDEzMC42Yy01LjEsMC05LjIsNC4xLTkuMiw5LjJjMCw1LjEsNC4xLDkuMiw5LjIsOS4yaDE0Ni41YzUuMSwwLDkuMi00LjEsOS4yLTkuMQ0KCVMyODIuMywyNDAuNCwyNzcuMiwyNDAuM3oiLz4NCjxwYXRoIGNsYXNzPSJzdDAiIGQ9Ik05My41LDI0MC4zSDY2LjRjLTUuMSwwLTkuMiw0LjEtOS4yLDkuMmMwLDUuMSw0LjEsOS4yLDkuMiw5LjJoMjcuMWM1LjEsMCw5LjItNC4xLDkuMi05LjINCglDMTAyLjcsMjQ0LjQsOTguNiwyNDAuMyw5My41LDI0MC4zeiIvPg0KPHBhdGggY2xhc3M9InN0MCIgZD0iTTI3Ny4yLDMxMy44SDEzMC42Yy01LjEsMC05LjIsNC4xLTkuMiw5LjJjMCw1LjEsNC4xLDkuMiw5LjIsOS4yaDE0Ni41YzUuMSwwLDkuMi00LjEsOS4yLTkuMQ0KCUMyODYuNCwzMTgsMjgyLjMsMzEzLjgsMjc3LjIsMzEzLjh6Ii8+DQo8cGF0aCBjbGFzcz0ic3QwIiBkPSJNOTMuNSwzMTMuOEg2Ni40Yy01LjEsMC05LjIsNC4xLTkuMiw5LjJjMCw1LjEsNC4xLDkuMiw5LjIsOS4yaDI3LjFjNS4xLDAsOS4yLTQuMSw5LjItOS4yDQoJQzEwMi43LDMxNy45LDk4LjYsMzEzLjgsOTMuNSwzMTMuOHoiLz4NCjxnPg0KCTxwYXRoIGNsYXNzPSJzdDAiIGQ9Ik0yNjMsNDEyLjFIODljLTQxLjQsMC03NS0zMy42LTc1LTc1di0yNDVjMC00MS40LDMzLjYtNzUsNzUtNzVoMTQ3LjVjOCwwLDE1LjcsMywyMS42LDguNWw2OSw2My42DQoJCWM2LjksNi4zLDEwLjgsMTUuMywxMC44LDI0Ljd2MjIzLjJDMzM4LDM3OC40LDMwNC40LDQxMi4xLDI2Myw0MTIuMXogTTg5LDM3LjNjLTMwLjIsMC01NC43LDI0LjYtNTQuNyw1NC43djI0NQ0KCQljMCwzMC4yLDI0LjYsNTQuNyw1NC43LDU0LjdoMTc0YzMwLjIsMCw1NC43LTI0LjYsNTQuNy01NC43VjExMy44YzAtMy43LTEuNi03LjMtNC4zLTkuOGwtNjktNjMuNmMtMi4yLTItNS0zLjEtNy45LTMuMUg4OXoiLz4NCjwvZz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K";
      }
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        .querySelector(".file__list")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          `<div>
                    <img src="${img}" alt="img"  title="${
            e.target.files[i].name
          }">
                    <div>
                        <span title="${e.target.files[i].name}">${
            e.target.files[i].name
          }</span>
                        <br/>
                        <small>${getFileSize(e.target.files[i].size)}</small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="delItem(this)" data-index="${i}" title="Remove This File"><span>&times;</span></button>
                </div>`
        );
    }
  }

  // set eror
  if (err.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < err.length; i += 1) {
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        .querySelector(".file__elements")
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          "afterbegin",
          `
            <div style="background: #fff2f2;color: darkred;display:none" class="file__error">
                <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="img">
                <span>${err[i]}</span>
            </div>`
        );
    }
    const errNods = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(
      ".file__elements>.file__error"
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < errNods.length; i += 1) {
      unfade(errNods[i]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        fade(errNods[i]);
      }, 3000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        errNods[i].remove();
      }, 4000);
    }
    err = [];
  }
}
```

```css
.file__upload {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file__upload>small {
  color: gray;
}

.file__upload>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  height: 35px;
}

.file__upload>button>img {
  width: 24px;
}

.file__upload>button>span,
.file__upload>span,
.file__upload>small {
  vertical-align: super;
}

.file__upload>input {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 37px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file__upload:hover {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.file__list>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}

.file__list>div>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 73%;
}

.file__list>div>div>small {
  color: gray;
}

.file__list>div>img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.file__list>div>div>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.file__list>div>button {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  padding: 0;
}

.file__list>div>button:hover {
  background: #bbbbbb;
}

.file__error {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 46px;
}

.file__error img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="file">
    <div class="file__upload">
      <button class="file__btn" type="button"> <img src="" alt=""> <span> Attach File</span></button>
      <span class="file__title">No File Chosen</span>
      <small class="file__max">(Max 1 MB)</small>
      <input multiple type="file" name="1" data-max="2">
    </div>
    <div class="file__elements">
      <div class="file__list">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/create-file-list@1.0.1/dist/create-file-list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Console error when there are multiple instances of the uploader. Try to test using the question HTML to see the error